# C array/pointer declaration syntax quiz

Tags: c, syntax, language-lawyer, declaration, c99

I thought I understood how C arrays, pointers and pointers to arrays worked, but now I stumbled upon a piece of working code which I don't understand:

```
int sum(const int * const buf, int len)
{
  int result = 0;
  const int (*p)[];
  int n;

  p = (const int(*)[]) buf;
  // p = buf without cast gives compiler warning here (but works)
  // p = (const int(*)[]) &buf;  // Doesn't work! Segfault!

  for( n=0; n<len; n++)
  {
    result += (*p)[n];
  }
  return result;
}
```

This actually works. But how? The question is: how does that assignment from "buf" to "p" work? I thought this declaration of p was similar to "pointer to pointer to int", so I would have expected a "&" necessesary at the assignment. Why is this not necessary?

In fact the following prototype also works (with the same function body above):

```
int sum(const int buf[const], int len)
```

Now it seems even more clear that the declaration of "p" adds one level of pointer re-direction compared to the declaration of "buf". Still ... the assignment works fine without any "&" necessary. Can someone explain it?

Comment: How is sum called?

Comment: In your example 'p' becomes a pointer to array of ints, this should then make more sense knowing this Oskar.

Comment: @Lundin: Yeah, I should have had a closer look, you're right. I removed my comments.

Comment: I added the "language-lawyer" tag to the question. This tag is useful when you have questions about code which is not necessarily of real-world production quality, but when you still wish to know what goes on between the lines.

Comment: Please stop stumbling around. You are tripping over a lot of garbage:(

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck: the call is straightforward, e.g.:
    int a[3] = {1,3,5}; return sum(a,3);

Comment: The pointer-to-array method used here is actually unnecessary--a plain old single-star pointer would have worked just fine and eliminated the weird parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please note that this code is not good practice. The pointer conversion is fishy-looking and unusual, and in particular it casts away const qualifiers, which is bad practice. (Declaring a parameter as `...* const buf` is pretty fishy to begin with though.)

> This actually works. But how?

There is a pointer conversion from (qualified) int pointer to int array pointer. Given that these two pointer types do not have different representation or different alignment (highly unlikely but theoretically possible), the pointer conversion in itself is ok (as per C11 6.3.2.3/8).

What matters then is the *effective type* of the data, which is an (array of) `int`. Effective type is a formal C term used for determining what type that is actually stored at a location, no matter the pointer types used for accessing. As long as the data is accessed through a pointer type that is compatible with the effective type of what's stored there, the code should work fine.

The formal reason why this is fine is C11 6.5/7 ("the strict aliasing rule"):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   /--/
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members

Where "aggregate" is C standard gibberish for arrays and structs. If we access the data through an expression of array type, where the array element type is a type/qualified type compatible with the actual type, `int` in this case, everything is fine.

As for how it works, it simply de-references an array pointer. `p = (const int(*)[]) buf;` says "threat what's stored in this variable as a pointer to array of integer (and qualifiers be damned)". Then `(*p)[n]` takes the array pointer, de-references it to get the actual array, then uses the array index.

> `p = buf` without cast gives compiler warning here

If you compile with `gcc -pedantic-errors` you get a more correct error. The pointer types are not compatible and so the compiler must generate a diagnostic message here - since `p = buf` is not valid C.

> `p = (const int(*)[]) &buf;`  // Doesn't work! Segfault!

This is because what's stored at `&buf` is not an array of int, it is just the pointer `buf` itself, likely allocated on the stack as a parameter to your function.

Comment: It would be good if you added a bold warning  the code is valid, though nothing one should write. Programmers should concentrate on writing clear code compiling without diagnostics, all recommended warnings enabled and no unjustified casts just to silence the compiler.

Comment: @Olaf Good point, I added a warning. I suspect that the original author of the code might have been some diva who has a pretty good level of C knowledge, but likes to show off too much. Those kind of programmers are even more dangerous than the clueless newbies, in my opinion.

Comment: I've seen enough code like this. I agree about the diva, but not the knowledge. I consider myself a bit diva-ish, too TBH, but I wouldn't use casts unless I can't get the types correct and exactly know their implications (in embedded programming you can't completely avoid them at the hardware level).

Comment: @Olaf Me, I would have declared the parameter as `const int const const signed * const const restrict const buf` just to show off my leet diva skills :)

Comment: That would violate the K.I.S.S principle. Fine then, I'm not a diva. I can live with that. Less money to spend for shoes ;-)

Comment: @Olaf No, this is an alternative design principle known as the [K.I.W.F](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kiwf) principle.

Comment: @Olaf: I just talked to the author of the code, the reason for these constructs was to try to satisfy a static analysis tool which didn't allow array syntax on pointer objects, e.g. complained at expressions containing "buf[n]" if "buf" was declared as a pointer and not as an array.

Comment: @Lundin: the code style tool complains unless "const" is used though. If the argument is not modified in the function a "const" qualifier is not bad practice IMO. But I think I understand what is happening now thanks to your analysis, thank you.

Comment: The rules of 6.5p7 unfortunately don't make provisions for accessing aggregate members of non-character type.  If `p` is an lvalue of type `int(*)[]` and `i` is an lvalue of some integer type, then `(*p)[i]` is an lvalue of type `int`, and nothing in 6.5p7 nor anywhere else that I can see would authorize the use of an `int`-type lvalue to access an object of type `int[]`.  While arrays would be useless if they couldn't be accessed in such fashion, I don't see anything in the rules that would actually allow it.

Comment: @supercat In case of `(*p)[i]`, you use an `int` to lvalue access an `int`, which is of course perfectly fine. It is "a type compatible with the effective type of the object". With your flawed reasoning, this code would also be UB: `int array[n] = ...; int* p = array; p[i] = something;`, since according to you, an `int` cannot be used to access an `int[]`.

Comment: @OskarEnoksson Sounds like a MISRA checker. The old MISRA-C:2004 had a nonsense rule which sounds exactly like what you describe. This rule has been removed in MISRA-C:2012 so the solution is to upgrade. Though the wild pointer conversion is a much more serious MISRA violation, so it doesn't solve anything... As for the const qualifier, the tool may complain if you don't do `const int* param`, but never if you don't do `int* const param`. If it does, the tool is broken.

Comment: @Lundin: Given the way the "type" of an lvalue is defined, 6.5p7 as written is ludicrous.  It's obvious that code like what you describe *should* have defined behavior, but that doesn't mean that the Standard is actually written in such a way that it *does*.  Nearly all of the confusion about what kinds of pointer operations are or are not allowed boil down to what kinds of things should "obviously" be legal, since the Standard makes no attempt to allow even the most obvious ones.

Comment: @supercat I agree that this part of the standard has plenty of room for improvements. However, you cannot reasonably use pointers at all if you don't regard an array type as effective type `int[n]`, which in turn contains `n` items each with the effective type `int`.

Comment: @Lundin: A literal reading of the Standard would render arrays essentially useless. The only way the language can be usable if programmers can rely upon compilers to predictably handle certain constructs the Standard doesn't require them to, but that any decent compiler "obviously" should, e.g. derive lvalue of type X from Y, perform all accesses to storage that will ever be done involving that storage and X without any intervening operations involving that storage without X, and then later use Y within the same context where X had been derived. If DR028 had said that a function which used...

Comment: ...two pointers which were derived before the function call to access members of the same union invoked UB because it accessed storage using lvalues of two types without either having been derived from the other in that context, rather than spouting some non-sequitur about implementation-defined representations, huge amounts of confusion and needless "effective type" nonsense could have been avoided.